# how to redirect to external url from observer sales_order_place_after

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway, redirect-url

I want to redirect to my external payment method after place order is Saved, I create an observer for event `sales_order_place_after`.

Inside execute I put this code

`$this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($this->url->getUrl(//ExternalURL like http://localhost))->sendResponse();`

but I get an error cors and I don't know how to fix or an alternative to redirect with dynamic variables inside URL like `http://localhost/example?variable1=example`

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
$this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect(http://gohilrajesh.blogspot.com)->sendResponse();
```

hope this helps you :)